# How to call an API through POST method

Tags: c#

I want to write a code in C# to call an API and pass necessary parameters through POST method in order to send an OTP to the given mobile number and return the response of the request.
API Base URL (API to call): https:/api.example.com/api/sendotp.php
Use these parameters to submit the request to the above API:
Auth key    : 146424AvL4aO2EHVS
Mobile no  : 0123456789
OTP            : 8480
Sender       : TDTECH

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET's `HttpClient` class.

```
private HttpClient Http = new HttpClient();
public async void DoRequest(string authKey, string mobile, string otp, string sender)
{
        var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authkey", authKey),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Mobile", mobile),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OTP", otp),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sender", sender),    
        });
        var response = await Http.PostAsync("https://api.example.com/api/sendotp.php", postData);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Handle content/response.
}
```